# exception when initialising cache causes "grails run-app" to fail

Tags: grails, ehcache

In my Grails 2.5.4 app I have the following plugins installed

```
compile ":cache:1.1.8"
runtime ":cache-ehcache:1.0.5"
```

When I run `grails run-app`, I get the following error at startup

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at grails.plugin.cache.ehcache.GrailsEhCacheManagerFactoryBean$ReloadableCacheManager.rebuild(GrailsEhCacheManagerFactoryBean.java:171)
    at grails.plugin.cache.ehcache.EhcacheConfigLoader.reload(EhcacheConfigLoader.groovy:63)
    at grails.plugin.cache.ConfigLoader.reload(ConfigLoader.groovy:42)
    at CacheGrailsPlugin.reloadCaches(CacheGrailsPlugin.groovy:202)
    at CacheGrailsPlugin$_closure3.doCall(CacheGrailsPlugin.groovy:158)
```

If I build the WAR and look in the `lib` directory, it contains both of the following dependencies:

- ehcache-2.9.0.jar
- ehcache-core-2.4.8.jar

Based on the advice in [this issue](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-cache-ehcache/issues/24), I excluded the transitive `ehcache-core` dependency in `BuildConfig`

```
runtime (":hibernate:3.6.10.18") { 
  excludes "ehcache-core" 
}
```

If I rebuild the WAR, the `ehcache-core` JAR *is* excluded, but I still get the same error at startup when I run `grails run-app`. I suspect the cause of the issue is the ehcache dependencies, but I can't figure out which JAR I should be using.

Comment: Run a `dependency-report` and look for inclusions of ehcache-core in some different version.  I don't have any grails 2 projects any more, but I recall that in an old one, we had to specifically exclude hibernate from plugin dependencies so that downstream dependencies would not be included as well.  I think that was related to caching.

Comment: For example, to exclude an older version of hibernate (which itself included an older version of ehcache-core) we modified the plugin inclusion like `compile(":shiro:1.2.1") { excludes "servlet-api", "hibernate", "quartz" }` once using dependency-report to identify what was including the old/incorrect dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to hibernate 3.6.10.19 seemed to resolve this issue. When I build the WAR the following ehcache dependencies are included:

- ehcache-2.9.0.jar
- hibernate-ehcache-3.6.10.Final.jar